# ReSharper adding binary refs instead of project refs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, resharper

We have an issue with ReSharper (7/VS2010): when you use it to add a reference from one project to another in the same solution sometimes it will add a binary reference to the output of the referenced project instead of a project refs.  Can this behavior be disabled, ideally so that it only adds project refs but failing that disable adding refs altogether?

Comment: I have never noticed this behavior. Can you tell us how to reproduce it?

Comment: this happens to me and you only realise its happened once your CI server builds. perhaps report this to jetbrains directly: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper

Comment: Consider posting the details to http://youtrack.jetbrains.net

Comment: I can confirm this is still an issue with R# 7 in VS2012.

Comment: I confirm it with R#8.1 and VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

This bug became known to JetBrains not longer after the original question was posed ([see it here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-333116#tab=Similar%20Issues)). It says it is fixed in ReSharper 8.0.14+. JetBrains is sometimes a little over-enthusiastic about declaring bugs to be closed; however there's a similar bug (see the list in the link above) that's supposedly fixed in R# 8.2, so there's a good chance this is no longer an issue with *that* version.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug in ReSharper and you need to open an issue for them as @wal has pointed out here: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper